# Null Pointer Error Swing and Database

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Below is the code, Spent Hour trying to track where is error... 
Code is much big... more then 45 Fields so more confused

```
Exception is `java.lang.NullPointerException`
```

code is

```
 String Scholno=getScholarNo();
 ScholarNo.setText(Scholno);
 addstudent = cnn.prepareStatement ("Insert into student(
    ScholarNo, Student_Name, Application_No, DateOfAdmission,
    Fathers_Name, Gender, DOB, Address, Session, Contact_no, Email, Course,
    Branch, Submitted_Documents, Nationality, GuardianName, GuardianContactNo,
    GuardianAddress, High_School_name, HS_Year_of_passing, HS_Percentage,
    HS_Board, Higher_secondary_Name, H_year_of_passing, H_percentage,
    H_board, Graduation, G_year_of_passing, G_percentage, G_University,
    Post_graduation, PG_year_of_passing, PG_percentage, PG_university,
    mother_name, religion, category, semester, section, status,Photo) ;
    values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

  addstudent.setString(1,ScholarNo.getText());
  addstudent.setString(2,StudentName.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(3,AdmissionNo.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(4,DateOfAdmission.getDate().toString());
  addstudent.setString(5,FatherName.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(6,Gender.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
  addstudent.setString(7, DOB.getDate().toString());
  addstudent.setString(8,Address.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(9,Session.getSelectedItem().toString());
  addstudent.setString(10,ContactNo.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(11,Email.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(12,Course.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
  addstudent.setString(13,Branch.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
  addstudent.setString(14,DocumentSubmitted.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(15,Nationality.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(16,GuardianName.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(17,GuardianContactNo.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(18,GuardianAddress.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(19,HS.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(20,HSYOP.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(21,HSPercentage.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(22,HSBoard.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(23,HSS.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(24,HSSYOP.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(25,HSSPercentage.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(26,HSSBoard.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(27,UG.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
  addstudent.setString(28,GYOP.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(29,GPercentage.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(30,GUniy.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(31,PG.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
  addstudent.setString(32,PGYOP.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(33,PGpercentage.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(34,PGUniy.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(35,MotherName.getText().trim());
  addstudent.setString(36,Religion.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
  addstudent.setString(37,Category.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
  addstudent.setString(38,Semester.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
  addstudent.setString(39,Section.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
  addstudent.setString(40,Status.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
  addstudent.setBytes(41,person_image);
  addstudent.executeUpdate();
} catch(Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

**Result of Stack**
run:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at projectmanagment.frmStudentRegistration.btnupdateActionPerformed(frmStudentRegistration.java:895)
    at projectmanagment.frmStudentRegistration.btnupdateActionPerformed(frmStudentRegistration.java:895)
    at projectmanagment.frmStudentRegistration.access$300(frmStudentRegistration.java:25)
    at projectmanagment.frmStudentRegistration$4.actionPerformed(frmStudentRegistration.java:563)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Can you put the stacktrace. it will have line number with that we can identify. There are lot of possibilites for null pointer exception in the code.

Comment: Bro Stacktrace Added

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Already have Viewed that topic but unable to detect the problem, Have understood why this problem occur but could not identify the source of error in code

Comment: You need to check what is written at Line number `895` of class `frmStudentRegistration.java`

Comment: at 895 it is -       addstudent.setString(4,DateOfAdmission.getDate().toString());

Comment: it is very difficult to guess for us. we can't see the line numbers. so better track the code in your machine. first remove the trim method, you may get null pointer for that also. later you find the code working add trim for each variable

Answer (score 0):

It got solved, error was regarding date which gave me null pointer Error, will post another Question for its answer so others are also benifited having same trouble